# Stripping received email headers in PHP

Tags: php, regex, email

I have a PHP script which has the source of an email. I aim to split the headers into variables `$To` and `$From`

The issue comes when trying to split the to and from strings up. What I need the script to do is take

```
From: John <john@somesite.com>
To: Susy <susy@mysite.com>, Steven <steven@somesite.com>, Mary <mary@mysite.com>
```

and return only the from address and the to addresses which are on my site. I.e.

```
$From = 'john@somesite.com';
$To = array('susy@mysite.com', 'mary@mysite.com');
```

So the code needs to turn a string of email addresses into an array and then filter out the ones from other sites. It's the first part that is proving difficult because of the different ways an email address can be listed in a header.

Comment: Maybe, you should add a regex tag to the question?

Comment: So where are you stuck? If you already have an array of all recipients, just filter it with `array_filter`.

Comment: What have you done so far? What did not work? Please share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php

 $k= "......Subject: Write the program any of your favorite language whenever if you feel
  you are free
 From: Vinay Kumar <vinaykumarjg@gmail.com>
 To: msnjsk@gmail.com, mithunsatish@gmail.com,Susy <susy@mysite.com>, Steven      <steven@somesite.com>, Mary <mary@mysite.com>
 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=bcaec53964ec5eed2604acd0e09a

 --bcaec53964ec5eed2604acd0e09a
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
 .......";


 if(preg_match('/From:(?P<text>.+)\r\n/', $k, $matches1))
 {

      if(preg_match('/(?P<from>([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])' .'(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+' . '(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)+)/', $matches1['text'],$sender ))
      {

         print_r($sender['from']);

      }

 }


 if(preg_match('/To:(?P<text>.+)\r\n/', $k, $matches2))
 {
    if(preg_match_all('/(?P<to>([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])' .
'(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+' . '(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)+)/', $matches2['text'], $reciever))
    {
        if(isset($reciever['to']))
        {
                print_r($reciever['to']);
        }
    }
 }
```

to get the subject:

```
 if(preg_match('/Subject:(?P<subject>.+)\r\n/', $k, $subject))
 {    

         print_r($subject['subject']);
 }
```

Comment: As far as I can see this works really well. Thanks for your help

Comment: Also, could this be expanded to also return the subject of the email to save me double processing everything? (I have no idea how regex works at all)

Comment: i have updated the answer. refer examples at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php ....

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

As you've now specified that you have the headers as a string *but* you actually need to parse the addresses from it, there is no need to reinvent the wheel:

- [`imap_rfc822_parse_headers`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-rfc822-parse-headers.php)
- [`imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-rfc822-parse-adrlist.php)

These two functions will do the job for you, the last one will give you an array with objects that have the email addresses pre-parsed, so you can easily take decisions based on the host.

---

It was not specifically clear to me what your actual problem is from your question.

As long as you are concerned about filtering a string containing one email address (cast it to array) or an array containing one or multiple addresses:

To filter the existing array of email-addresses you can use a simple array mapping function that will set any email that is not matching your site's host to `FALSE` and then filter the array copy [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/s4as0Q):

```
$addresses = array(
   'mary@mysite.com',
   'mary@othersite.com',
);

$myhost = 'mysite.com';

$filtered = array_map(function($email) use ($myhost) {
    $host = '@'.$myhost;
    $is = substr($email, -strlen($host)) === $host;
    return $is ? $email : FALSE;
}, $addresses);

$filtered = array_filter($filtered);

print_r($filtered);
```

This codes makes the assumption that you have the email addresses already gathered. You have not specified how you parse the headers already in your question, so it's actually unknown with which data you are dealing, so I opted to start from the end of your problem. Let us know if you have more information available.

Comment: Once I have the email addresses the processing part isn't an issue. The issue comes from the fact that there could be 1 or 20 addresses and they can be in different formats all within the one string.

Comment: Do you have any specification to follow, like the RFC's for email messages, or does it need only to match your exacts examples you've given in your question?

Comment: I'd go with the RFCs because the emails could be coming from anyone using any piece of software

Comment: I don't think you're really understanding the question. I have the headers of an email as a block of text and I need to extract from that block of text the addresses the emails is being sent to and the email address it is being sent from. THEN I need to filter out the ones which aren't going to my site. Sorry if I'm not explaining myself very well.

Comment: I updated the question with two functions that should do the job for you.

Comment: Wow, PHP continues to amaze me with how many great prebuilt functions it has. Thanks for your help and patience with my inability to explain things well :)

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all("/<([^><]+)/", $headers, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => john@somesite.com
    [1] => susy@mysite.com
    [2] => steven@somesite.com
    [3] => mary@mysite.com
)
```

The first one is always **From** email address.

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/ez1Vf9)